# Pygame: player sprite colliding incorrectly and clipping into wall

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I am creating a 4-way movement, tile based rpg. The code I have written for collision detection is relatively simple but I have a minor graphical error.

The player moves directly between evenly spaced tiles. To control the speed the player moves at there is a walk buffer of 200 seconds. When the player collides with a wall, they should be pushed back in the same direction they hit the wall. This works, however, very briefly the player sprite will flicker in the wall.

I suspect it's to do with the player update function and how that's ordered but I've messed around with it to no avail.

````
import sys
vec = pg.math.Vector2

WHITE =     ( 255, 255, 255)
BLACK =     (   0,   0,   0)
RED =       ( 255,   0,   0)
YELLOW =    ( 255, 255,   0)
BLUE =      (   0,   0, 255)

WIDTH = 512 # 32 by 24 tiles
HEIGHT = 384
FPS = 60
TILESIZE = 32
PLAYER_SPEED = 3 * TILESIZE

MAP = ["1111111111111111",
       "1P.............1",
       "1..............1",
       "1..1111........1",
       "1..1..1........1",
       "1..1111.111111.1",
       "1............1.1",
       "1........111.1.1",
       "1........1...1.1",
       "1........11111.1",
       "1..............1",
       "1111111111111111"]


def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
    return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.rect)

def player_collisions(sprite, group):
    hits_walls = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
    if hits_walls:
        sprite.pos -= sprite.vel * TILESIZE




class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.walk_buffer = 200
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(x, y) *TILESIZE
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0
        self.walking = False
        
        self.walking_sprite = pg.Surface((TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.walking_sprite.fill(YELLOW)
        
        self.image = self.walking_sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hit_rect = self.rect
        self.hit_rect.bottom = self.rect.bottom


    def update(self):
        self.get_keys()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

        self.pos += self.vel * TILESIZE
        
        self.hit_rect.topleft = self.pos
        player_collisions(self, self.game.walls)

        self.rect.midbottom = self.hit_rect.midbottom


    def get_keys(self):        
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        
        if now - self.last_update > self.walk_buffer:
            self.vel = vec(0,0)
            self.last_update = now
            if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
                self.vel.x = -1
            elif keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
                self.vel.x = 1
            elif keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
                self.vel.y = -1
            elif keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
                self.vel.y = 1



class Obstacle(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE
        self.w = TILESIZE
        self.h = TILESIZE
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((self.w,self.h))
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hit_rect = self.rect
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption("Hello Stack Overflow")
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        pg.key.set_repeat(500, 100)

    def new(self):
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        for row, tiles in enumerate(MAP):
            for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
                if tile == "1":
                    Obstacle(self, col, row)
                elif tile == "P":
                    print("banana!")
                    self.player = Player(self, col, row)

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def run(self):
        # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()


    def events(self):
        # catch all events here
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()


    def update(self):
        self.player.update()


    def draw(self):
        self.screen.fill(WHITE)
        for wall in self.walls:
            self.screen.blit(wall.image, wall.rect)
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            self.screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)
    

        pg.display.flip()



# create the game object
g = Game()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
    
pg.quit()```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the rect before checking for collision but not resetting it after the collision check.

Here is the updated code (in Player class, update method):

```
self.hit_rect.topleft = self.pos
player_collisions(self, self.game.walls)  # may change postion
self.hit_rect.topleft = self.pos  # reset rectangle
```